# How and where do i start learning creating project with node, webpack, redux, react?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux

I want to make a web application with frontend of node, webpack, redux, react and backend with rails api project. I did't find any tutorial with all of these. I need some solution where i have to start learning and creating my project?
[There are lot of tutorial/ebooks/documentation separately of each part but i need a path with those part in a single tutorial or documentation]
And also want some tutorial how i can connect with rails api project and frontend project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js and Ruby on Rails are actually competing server side technologies.  In ordinary cases you would like to use one or the other, but not both.

Please clarify.

Otherwise I would recommend [Modern React with Redux](https://www.udemy.com/react-redux/learn/) for front end Web development and [Learn and Understand Node.js](https://www.udemy.com/understand-nodejs/learn/) for server side.